# EXC_BAD_ACCESS pointing me an arm line of code

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, compiler-construction, arm

I´m trying to know what I´m doing wrong because the console is giving me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, just in the arm line I´m pointing below.
Any pointing to the solution could help, because I don´t understand why is giving me this error.

Thanks.

```
 /*
 * Copyright (c) 1999-2007 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
 */

#ifndef _OS_OSBYTEORDERARM_H
#define _OS_OSBYTEORDERARM_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <arm/arch.h> /* for _ARM_ARCH_6 */

 #if !defined(OS_INLINE)
# if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#        define OS_INLINE static inline
# else
 #        define OS_INLINE static __inline__
# endif
#endif

 * Generic byte swapping functions. */

OS_INLINE
uint16_t
 _OSSwapInt16(
  uint16_t        data
  )
 {
  #if defined(__llvm__)
 data = (data << 8 | data >> 8);
#elif defined(_ARM_ARCH_6)
  __asm__ ("rev16 %0, %1\n" : "=l" (data) : "l" (data));   <- This is the line pointed by the compiler
```

Comment: Did you enable zombie detection?

Comment: What's the backtrace look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> <- This is the line pointed by the compiler

Therewith you say that the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs during compilation. If a compiler throwed such an exception during its work, it would dump it and get me a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but I am giving you just idea that The error means you are trying to access the null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the short (16-bit) data type you are using. Try 32-bit for the sake of testing.

Also, I never used rev16 but I doubt really this is the intended function you need.

```
   uint32_t        data2;
   data2 = data;
   __asm__ ("rev16 %0, %1\n" : "=l" (data2) : "l" (data2));   <- This is the line pointed by
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to swap the bytes of a 16-bit integer (or a method you are using is trying to swap the bytes of a 16-bit integer) but the integer resides in memory that you do not own. It could be at the `NULL` address, or it may be in an address that was recently deallocated.